# Clicking a link in PDF file

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

Some help needed with clicking link in downloaded pdf file.

With C#, Selenium and AutoIt , i have downloaded a pdf file. Now i want to open that pdf file and click on dynamic link that is placed in page 2.
I was able to open pdf but didnt got to know how to click link in pdf. some help needed

Comment: c#, i am not sure. Java or Python, SIKULI can be used.

Answer (score 2):

Web driver does not support clicking links inside a PDF - use an open source pdf API - Apache pdfbox- this will extract all the links and then you can navigate further with webdriver.